# Avoiding my global variables in Python, I have several functions that change one variable

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I am trying to get rid of my global variables but I am not sucessful doing so.

In this case I let the user assign coordinates when I run the program. From those coordinates we are starting to sail a boat (within a matrix) meaning that the functions I have that control movement need to have access to these coordinates from the input function. Also the movement functions need to assign new values to the coordinates.

```
koordx = 0
koordy = 0

distancetraveled = 0

def input ():
    global koordx
    global koordy


    koordx = int(input ("Assign Y coordinate)"))
    koordy = int(input("Assign Y coordinate"))

       ..... etc
```

This is example of movement, changing the coordinates.

```
def north ():
    global distancetraveled
    distancetraveled += 2
    global koordy
    koordy -= 1


def northeast():
    global distancetraveled
    distancetraveled += 2
    global koordx
    koordx += 1
    global koordy
    koordy -= 1

def movement():
    if... . .. :
       northeast() etc... #moves northeast

input()

movement()
```

This is just an example, I have some more functions that need to access these coordinates and their values. How can I in a smooth way get rid of my global variables?

This is just a section of my code which I modified to make it more understandable what I need help with.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wow, this came out quite a mess, but I hope you understand that the code beside the function definition are supposed to be inside the function. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You could create a Boat class, and encapsulate the coordinates and distance within instances of Boat:

```
class Boat:
    def __init__(self, x, y, dist=0):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         self.dist=dist
```

Then you can either create functions that operate on Boats, and modify those variables, or you can create methods within the Boat class that operate on the variables (which is a more object-oriented way of doing this, and encapsulates the state better)

Comment: Thank you, and a huge thanks to the guy who edited my post! I actually tried a solution like yours before I started this thread. I did not quite succeed in changing the variables within the constructor since if I assign values within the methods they are local to that method. Would you mind explaining further?